# Close votes combine and falsely attribute close reasons

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32466/599) several users voted to close the question as a duplicate. I did not agree with this, but I thought the question could use some more clarification (specifically reference images), so I CVed as "unclear what you are asking".

Regardless of who was "right", it now displays me as having voted to close as a duplicate even though I most certainly did not:

[image]

I've read [Close Vote Reason Logic When There Isn't a Majority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187300/238438) which explains the logic of how the close reason is picked, but not *why* it's picked (why couldn't the message list all close reasons next the the names of the appropriate close-voters?).

Even if it was displayed more like this:

> **Closed** by user1, user2, user3, user4, user5 some time ago.
>   <sub>This question has been marked as a duplicate of xyz question. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.</sub>

I feel like it would be an improvement as it wouldn't directly assert that all the users voted for the displayed close reason.

After reading [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/238438), it appears this feature has been known for a long time. In which case my question is why have there been no plans to change this? By what reasoning is this feature desired behavior?

Comment: I just found [this question from 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/238438). Are there still really no plans to change this? It seems pretty unjustifiable for the site to *deliberately display false information*.

Comment: I absolutely agree about this!

Comment: Does that last link link to this question? O.o

Comment: @muru Oops, fixed